# How to measure the detection time with the yolov3 darknet in seconds?

Tags: real-time, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I'm working with darknet yolov3 based on this github: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

I can detect my objects properly, but I would like to measure the time of detection.

For example, the time person (my subject is a person) leaves the room and the time person returns to the room. I want that delta to measure how long it was outside the room between those two detection times and then to print it out in seconds.

Could you help me with this matter, please?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Forough, can you post some context? By that I mean some code based on your yolov3, we need to understand every point to help you.

Comment: @RobertoGonçalves I don't have a specific code to measure the time of detection. I used the main repository to detect objects. Here is the github: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

Comment: Sure, but others need some context to be based, otherwise will be very difficult to help you. You need to provide something that we can rely on.

Comment: Do you mean two person who leaves the room and returns to the room are same person? I mean do you need to identify person who he/she is?

Comment: @RoyLee No, I just need a person to be detected. It's not important to me who he or she is. Just the person. In my case, It's always the same person. I don't need to identify it, then.